# Cannot make a search in AD by computer mask

Tags: powershell

I want to find description of computer in AD by specific word that exists in Description.

```
$username = "test111"   
Get-ADComputer -filter {Description -Like 'test111*'} -Properties Description | select Description # this works ok
Get-ADComputer -filter {Description -Like "$username*"} -Properties Description | select Description # shows nothing, no error
```

How can I make the search using variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a query like this:

```
$username = "test111" 
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Description -Like '$username*'" -Properties Description | Select -Expand Description
```

I think what was happening is that `$username` was probably `$null` since it was not passed to the script block. Changing the `-Filter` to be using quotes allows the variable to expand properly. Threw and `-Expand` in there so you just get back a string array instead of an Object array.